# Rails linking issue database

Tags: ruby-on-rails

New to rails and I'm wondering the best method to approach this problem.

I have an index, list and result pages in views:

My route file has:

```
resources :pages do
 collection do  
  get :list
  get :result
 end
end
```

I have a mysql database called results with id, year(2000 -> 2013), product_name.

My controller has:

```
def index
@years = Result.group('year').order('year DESC')
end
```

My index view has:

```
<table class="table">
<% @years.each do |year| %>
<tr><td>
<%= link_to year.year, list_pages_path %>
</td></tr>
<% end %>
</table>
```

Which lists the years from 2000 -> 2013 fine and what i'm wanting it to do is to link to the list view and list the products and year which have been selected on the previous link_to index(e.g. 2013 which would list all 2013 products from the database), which then links to the result view showing more product info.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement a scope on the pages model that will filter by year:

```
class Pages < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :year, ->(year) { where(year: year) }
end
```

Then change the `link_to` to send a query parameter for the year:

```
link_to year.year, list_pages_path(year: year.year)
```

Finally, in the controller

```
def list
    @pages = Page.year(params[:year])
end
```

You'll need to make sure you've wired up the correct action - I think it will default to `PagesController#year`.

Also, to be thorough, you'll want to make sure you check the input to prevent SQL injection. Perhaps something like:

```
def list
  @pages = Page.year(Integer(params[:year])
end
```

This will throw an exception if `params[:year]` can't be converted to an integer. Since you're not allowing the user to enter the parameter anywhere, they'll only see the exception if they try to maliciously tamper with the url. You may still want to handle it more gracefully, though.

Comment: Thanks you for the quick response. Your solution worked a treat. Many thanks!